# How to get time interval until date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I would like to get the time interval from the present date and time until a certain date in the future. All I could manage to do is get the interval but with a minus in front of all, because i used this:

```
let elapsedTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(GeneralUtils.dateFromString(endDate))

let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .Abbreviated
let countdown = formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(elapsedTime)

timerLabel.text! = "\(countdown!)"
```

How could I fix it to show me the positive interval?
Now it shows me something like this "-1d 3h 23m 10s"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Just use `abs()` so the time interval is always positive.</del> (Just me being insane)

Of course [Russell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950044/how-to-get-time-interval-until-date/34950131#comment57631771_34950131) points out you could just swap the dates around...

```
let elapsedTime = GeneralUtils.dateFromString(endDate).timeIntervalSinceNow
```

Comment: Or swap the dates around!

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel `GeneralUtils.dateFromString(endDate).timeIntervalSinceNow`